# SOAP uses different datetime format

Tags: c#, soap, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

In `Dynamics Nav (2013)` I have a codeunit that is accessible with the soap services to run a `XML` port. If I enter in the proper URI for this codeunit to run the port, the `XML` data is imported OK. Also if I just run the `XMLPORT.IMPORT` function from in `NAV` is will properly import the `XML` data file.

But if I use the `SoapHttpClientProtocol` class to run the codeunit then the dates that are in the XML data are imported backwards. The months and days are switched around. I have tried copying my regional settings to the Network Service account with no luck.

Any other possible fixes or reasons on why the data-time format is different when ran through code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in my long lost search for why this bug is happening I finally stumbled upon this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2012/11/07/nav-2013-soap-web-services-on-a-multilanguage-environment.aspx

All SOAP operations are forced to use EN-US culture and  CANNOT be changed.  But it seems that this has been reverted in a new build of 2013 R2 in April. You just have to add:
`<add key="ServicesCultureDefaultUserPersonalization" value="true"/>`
to your CustomSettings.config file (if you are using a service instance, ensure you change the proper one under `[path-to-NAV]\71\Service\Instances\` folder) and it should use whatever culture you have in the user personalization table